# expected identifier or '(' before '{' token in Flex

Tags: c, compiler-errors, yacc, flex-lexer

I am trying to use `flex` and `yacc` to parse 'C' source code. Unfortunately I am getting the error "expected identifier or '(' before '{' token" on lines 1,12,13,14... . Any ideas why?

This is my flex file (called mini.l):

```
%{

%}
digit [0-9]
letter [a-zA-Z]
number (digit)+
id (letter|_)(letter|digit|_)*
integer (int)
character (char)
comma [,]
%%
{integer} {return INT;}
{character} {return CHAR;}
{number} {return NUM;}
{id} {return IDENTIFIER;}
{comma} {return ',';}
[-+*/] {return *yytext;}
. {}
%%
main()
{
   yylex();
}
```

The corresponding yacc file (called my_yacc.y) is as shown below:

```
%{
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
/* #include "myhead.h" */
#include "mini.l"
#define YYSTYPE double
# undef fprintf
%}

%token INT
%token CHAR
%token IDENTIFIER
%token NUM
%token ','
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%right UMINUS

%%

lines:lines expr '\n' {printf("%g\n",$2);}
      |lines '\n'
      |D
      |     
      ;
expr :expr '*' expr {$$=$1*$3;}
     |expr '/' expr {$$=$1/$3;}
     |expr '+' expr {$$=$1+$3;}
     |expr '-' expr {$$=$1+$3;}
     |'(' expr ')' {$$=$2;}
     |'-' expr %prec UMINUS {$$=-$2;}
     |IDENTIFIER {}
     |NUM   {}  
     ;
T    :INT {}
     |CHAR {}
     ;
L    :L ',' IDENTIFIER {}
     |IDENTIFIER {}
     ;
D    :T L {printf("T is %g, L is %g",$1,$2);}
     ;

%%
/*void yyerror (char *s)
{
  fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", s);
}  
*/
```

I am compiling the generated code using the commands:

```
flex mini.l
yacc my_yacc.y
gcc y.tab.c -ly
```

Comment: Where are you getting the error? When running flex or at compiling the generated flex code? I just tried: flex runs your code without any error. Its ok. An the compiler just compalins on the undefined CHAR/INT/NUM/..., but only they are not defined in the file, I guess you have them in some other include file.

Comment: @flolo Yes, we are getting the error while compiling the generated code. We are using yacc to parse the file, and we have defined INT/CHAR/NUM... in yacc file. But the errors are obtained even before reading those tokens.

Comment: Better, but we still need more information. You're showing us two files, but you're not telling us their names. You're showing us a single command, `gcc my_file.c -ly`, but what is `my_file.c`? If the first block of code is `my_file.`, then that's your problem; you need to rename it and feed it to `flex`, not to `gcc`, since it's not C code.

Comment: The flex code file name is "mini.l" , the yacc file name is "my_yacc.y"  ..... commands used  :- flex mini.l, yacc my_yacc.y,gcc y.tab.c -ly

Answer (score 2):

The errors you are seeing are coming from the C compiler and are caused by you misunderstanding of how flex and yacc work together. When I run it though the same tools as you, I get the following errors, as you also do, and as noted by @KeithThompson:

```
In file included from my_yacc.y:5:0:
mini.l:1:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '%' token
 %{
 ^
mini.l:5:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before' letter'
 letter [a-zA-Z]
 ^
mini.l:12:11: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {integer} {return INT;}
           ^
... elided the rest ...
```

Although you have used the commands `flex`, `yacc` and `gcc` in the correct sequence, you have included the file `mini.l` in your bison input. This is incorrect. You should be including the **output** of the flex that was *created* from `mini.l`. This file is called `lex.yy.c`. It is also necessary to include this *at the end* on the yacc input file. (This is because if you don't you get the error found by @flolo). If you make the necessary changes to your `yacc` file, you will have this:

```
%{
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
/* #include "myhead.h" */
/* #include "mini.l" */

#define YYSTYPE double
# undef fprintf
%}

%token INT
%token CHAR
%token IDENTIFIER
%token NUM
%token ','
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%right UMINUS

%%

lines:lines expr '\n' {printf("%g\n",$2);}
      |lines '\n'
      |D
      |     
      ;
expr :expr '*' expr {$$=$1*$3;}
     |expr '/' expr {$$=$1/$3;}
     |expr '+' expr {$$=$1+$3;}
     |expr '-' expr {$$=$1+$3;}
     |'(' expr ')' {$$=$2;}
     |'-' expr %prec UMINUS {$$=-$2;}
     |IDENTIFIER {}
     |NUM   {}  
     ;
T    :INT {}
     |CHAR {}
     ;
L    :L ',' IDENTIFIER {}
     |IDENTIFIER {}
     ;
D    :T L {printf("T is %g, L is %g",$1,$2);}
     ;

%%
void yyerror (char *s)
{
  fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", s);
}  

#include "lex.yy.c"
```

If you run your command sequence on this now, you will find it both compiles and runs, and also process C language input correctly.

The mistake you made is a common error made by new users to the tools `flex` and `yacc`.

Comment: This question was flagged as "fault not reproducible", [but the flag timed out as it did for hundreds of others, and once flagged it cannot be re-flagged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287165/why-were-my-older-close-flags-aged-away). The question had some up-votes so some people felt it a good question worth answering, so I thought it worth answering an closing.